# Google analytics not installed

Tags: html, google-analytics

I am developing my personal portfolio, but can't get Google Analytics working after many trials.
This is the code I have for tracking, but no data shows up still.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poiret+One" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="css/myStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<title>Hang Yuan</title>
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-55002898-2', 'auto'); 
ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
</head>
```

This is the website link: hangyuan.co
Thanks!

Comment: I see your code in the page. Either the code is incorrect or your Google profile ID is incorrect. Also, GA won't immediately see your page. It takes a bit of time to re-index.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right. Now I can see the GA result now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine as others have mentioned - have you checked in your Real-Time reports to see if your simultaneous visits show up? If you had just installed your analytics, then it will take at least 24 hours for the data to show up in your standard reports; your status may also indicate "Tracking not installed". If you can see your real-time reports, then you should be fine, and you just need to wait for the status to update.

Comment: I guess all the answers are right. It really takes time for Google Analytics to collect data after the tracking ID is inserted by the header. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your host is using a CDN it is probably caching your old site. It could take up to 24 hours to recache the site, and for Google to grab the code.

EDIT: Checked your site, the code is fine. Just let Google index it and find it...